# Dual Boot full disk encryption greyed out

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, encryption

I'm trying to install a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.10, both fully encrypted.

I have a 230 GB SSD and installed Windows in the first 100 GB.

Now I'm trying to install Ubuntu using the rest of the disk. The problem is, that during the Ubuntu installation, the two options

- **Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security** and
- **Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation**

are both greyed out. Why is that so?

Is this because I'm trying to install both on the same SSD?

Is there a way to encrypt both installations on one disk?

Comment: The encryption of Windows should have no impact on the encryption of Ubuntu and vice-versa. Provide more information: do you use BIOS or UEFI to boot; is the disk partitioned using a MBR or a GPT partition table; what does the disk appear like in Ubuntu (output of `lsblk`, `parted -l`, `fdisk -l`); what does the disk look like to the installer (start the installation and choose "Something else").

Answer (score 0):

Dislaimer: This is not a fully detailed/verified answer yet. I will update it when I install again.

So my setup: Non-EFI. 500GB hard drive. Preinstalled with windows 10. I shrank my Windows 10 partition to 80GB. Turned on BitLocker. Created an Ubuntu 16.04 install USB drive.

When installing Ubuntu, I hit the same problem as you where the 'encrypt' option was grayed out on dual-boot (but I did verify that non-encrypted install works just fine).

To get past this, I selected `Try Ubuntu`. When in call from a Terminal `sudo swapoff -a`

Run `sudo gparted` to verify that the unallocated space you want to allocate is accurate.

Run `Install Ubuntu 16.04` from the desktop. When you get to the location where the encrypted option was grayed out originally, select `Do something else` to specify partitions manually. For the partitions, I first created an ext4 of 20GB (note: waaay too big) and put the mount point at `/boot`. Then I created a `physical drive for encryption` that took the remainder of the disk. The new logical drive created should have its mount point set to `/`. Then press install. It will complain about there being no swap drive. Press OK because swap can be turned on later.

At this point, install should proceed as normal.

Note that as soon as the encrypted drive is selected, things get messy as the new partition is officially created. At this point, I'm no longer able to boot without the Ubuntu USB disk. To get aroudn that I can either a) use gparted to delete the newly created partition and try again or b) just install unencrypted Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

It seems, that the ubuntu-auto installer does only work if he can encrypt the whole disk.

I fixed the issue by doing the partioning by hand before the actual installation wizard. (I followed [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/System_verschl%C3%BCsseln/) german tutorial)

Comment: Please add details. Putting a link to instructions doesn't make a good answer. See ["Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)